# Diagonalization: Am i finding these eigenvectors wrongly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&-8\\ 0&-1&0\\ 0&0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-4&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Confirm that P diagonalizes A. I want to do this by first finding the eigen values and vectors of A then show how these match up with P's columns.

because its an upper triangular  $det(A- \lambda I = (1-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)=0$ easily so eigenvalues are 1 and -1 whose multiplicity is 2. Which means -1 must have two free valuables meaning a geometric multiplicity of 2 to be diagonalizable.

So i row reduce $A-I$ and get
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-2&-8\\ 0&-2&0\\ 0&0&-2 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
which if if multiplied $R_2$ and $R_3$ by $-\frac{1}{2}$ to get two leading 1s
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-2&-8\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
then reducing $R_1$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
I get that $X_1 = t$ so for row 2 $$t+X_2 = 0$$ $$x_2 = -t $$ and like wise $$X_3 = t$$

Which is a vector $t\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ which doesn't correspond with any column of P even if i change t around for a different value.

Also if i don't multiply $R_{1,2}$ by $-\frac{1}{2}$ and reduce by only multiples of row 2 and row 3 i ge that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-0&0\\ 0&-2&0\\ 0&0&-2 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
in which $X_1 = t \quad X_{2,3}=-\frac{1}{2}t$

$t\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$ 
which almost make sense weren't for row 1 being a half.

Comment: The easiest way to show that P diagonalizes A is to show that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Gives $x_1$ as a free variable, and the other two lines give $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$. The eigenspace is therefore:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = x_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: But i got thought $X_1 = t$ and then $R_2 = t+X_2=0$ and $R_3= t+X_3=0$

Comment: You should still get $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 =0 $ from the second and third rows.

Comment: But How do you get the 0s?

Comment: Oh shoot i just got it... $X_1 = t$ still carries on but i haven't been taking into account the coefficients of $X_1$ $R_2 = 0*t + X_2 = 0$ and $R_3= 0*t +X_x$

Answer (score 0):

We say that a matrix $P$ **diagonalizes** a matrix $A$ if $P^{-1} A P$ is diagonal. In our case, however, we have
$$
P^{-1} A P =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -16 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not diagonal. This means that the given $P$ does not diagonalize the given $A$.

Comment: I thought it was if P satisfied $A=PDP^{-1}$

Comment: If you multiply the equation $A=PDP^{-1}$ on the left by $P^{-1}$ and on the right by $P$ what do you get?